# Pyspark Dataframe aggregation-count on different condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to aggregation (count) on two different condition and try to assign to two different columns. Can anyone suggest me any easy method to do?

In the solution below which I have tried the counts are coming same though the filter conditions are different,

```
num_ins_rec_cnt = F.count(col("ins_upd_flag") == "I").alias("ins_rec_cnt")
num_upd_rec_cnt = F.count(col("ins_upd_flag") == "U").alias("upd_rec_cnt")
delta_process_max_ld_df = cdc_all_record_sk_ld_df.agg(F.max('delta_account_sk_id').alias("max_account_sk_id"),(num_ins_rec_cnt),(num_upd_rec_cnt)).withColumn("lkp_process_name",lit(process_name)).withColumn("history_tbl_cnt",lit(base_rec_count)).withColumn("delta_tbl_cnt",lit(delta_rec_count))
```

The output is,

```
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+
|max_account_sk_id|ins_rec_cnt|upd_rec_cnt|    lkp_process_name|history_tbl_cnt|delta_tbl_cnt|
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+
|            25099|       5100|       5100|amc_account_delta_ld|          19999|        20099|
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

But it should have been,

```
+-------+---------------+--+
|  _c0  | ins_upd_flag  |
+-------+---------------+--+
| 5100  | I             |
| 5000  | U             |

Sample Data:
+--------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+
|delta_acct_nbr|delta_account_sk_id|delta_zip_code|delta_primary_state|delta_eff_start_date|delta_eff_end_date|      delta_load_tm|      delta_hash_key|delta_eff_flag|ins_upd_flag|
+--------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+
|   ID330020000|              20000|         02345|                 CA|          2016-11-10|        3099-12-31|2016-11-10 14:53:52|19DEDD4F9A55845E8...|             Y|           I|
|   ID330020001|              20001|         02345|                 CA|          2016-11-10|        3099-12-31|2016-11-10 14:53:52|19DEDD4F9A55845E8...|             Y|           I|
|   ID330020002|              20002|         02345|                 CA|          2016-11-10|        3099-12-31|2016-11-10 14:53:52|19DEDD4F9A55845E8...|             Y|
```

Comment: Yes.. correct.. As I have to write into a table as separate column . I need filter output t two separate columns.

Answer (score -2):

I have solved the prob in below way.

delta_process_max_ld_df = cdc_all_record_sk_ld_df.withColumn('ins_upd_flag_cnt', ****F.when(cdc_all_record_sk_ld_df.ins_upd_flag == 'I', 1).when(cdc_all_record_sk_ld_df.ins_upd_flag == 'U', 0).otherwise(0))**.agg(F.max('delta_account_sk_id').alias("max_surrogate_id"),F.sum('ins_upd_flag_cnt').alias("insert_record_cnt"),F.count('*').alias("ins_upd_count"))**.withColumn("process_name",lit(process_name)).withColumn("process_run_date",lit(load_dt)).withColumn("base_tbl_cnt",lit(base_rec_count)).withColumn("delta_tbl_cnt",lit(delta_rec_count)).withColumn("load_tm",lit(load_tm)).withColumn("tbl_name",lit(tgt_tbl_nm)).withColumn("load_date",lit(process_run_date))#.select(*status_tbl_columns)
        delta_process_max_ld_df1 = **delta_process_max_ld_df.withColumn("upd_record_cnt",lit(delta_process_max_ld_df.ins_upd_count - delta_process_max_ld_df.insert_record_cnt))**.select(*status_tbl_columns)